# ERRO RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart

Ocorreu um erro que não sei como resolver no Flutter:

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

A ideia é carregar uma página de profile e esse dado é recuperado com `http.post` via JSON.

O problema é porque o objeto não existe até terminar de carregar o JSON que vem via HTTP.

Mas eu não sei como resolver. Segue meu código:

```dart
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MapScreenState createState() => MapScreenState();
}

class MapScreenState extends State<ProfilePage> {

  var users = new List<Users>();

  MapScreenState() {
   // Recupera os dados via json
    _getDataProfile();
  }

_getDataProfile() async {
    var token = "ASDSDSADCSADASDSADASD";

    final ws = Webservice();
    ws.startLoading(context);

    ws.getPerfil(token).then((ret) {
      String retorno = ret["data"].toString();

      setState(() {
        Iterable lista = json.decode(json.encode(ret["data"]));
        users = lista.map((model) => Users.fromJson(model)).toList();

      });
    });

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

            log(users[index].user_name.toString());
          }
        },
      ),
  }
}
```

Como resolver o `users[index]`? Pois ele não existe até terminar o carregamento do `http.post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para você aguardar uma requisição e só depois construir sua tela, é preciso utilizar o Widget `FutureBuilder`, abaixo deixo um exemplo:

```
Future<List<Users>> _getDataProfile() async {
    var token = "ASDSDSADCSADASDSADASD";

    final ws = Webservice();
    ws.startLoading(context);

    final ret = await ws.getPerfil(token);
    String retorno = ret["data"].toString();
    Iterable lista = json.decode(json.encode(ret["data"]));
    var users = lista.map((model) => Users.fromJson(model)).toList();
    return users;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _getDataProfile,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Center(child: Text("Carregando..."));
            
            List<Users> users = snapshot.data;

            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                log(users[index].user_name.toString());
              }
            ),
        })
    )
}
```

*~~ Pode haver alguns pequenos erros no tipo das variáveis do método `_getDataProfile()` mas ai você ajusta.*

*Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre esse Widget na documentação [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).*